# Laravel mutate date before saving to database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime

I have a date that's being selected in a datepicker in the following format

```
Y-m-d g:i A
```

So using AM/PM, it shows the following in my input field, which is correct

[image]

When I submit the form offcourse Laravel won't update the record because the format is unknown to my DATETIME field in mysql.

**My 'date' field is added to the $dates array so it should be parsed by Laravel**

> I tried using a Mutator on my Model as following, without success

```
public function setDateAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d g:i A', $value)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

The original value is not being updated.
Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Does it through anny error when you submit form ?

Comment: Nope! It just doesn't update the value in my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's date mutator expects a format like `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`, but you can use the `$dateFormat` attribute on your model to specify a different format. E.g.:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d g:i A';
```

Check out the **Date Formats** section in the docs under [Date Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

Alternatively, you can parse the date using Carbon outside of the model, because attributes listed in the `$dates` will also accept Carbon instances:

```
$model->date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d g:i A', '2016-11-29 02:00 PM');
```

This is the approach I typically use. To me this feels more like a front-end concern where you're trying to map a user-friendly format to one your models/DB expects, so I'll usually put this logic into a controller.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so confused with all this.. It's indeed obvious to save it in the database using the default but showing it otherwise and then retransforming it in the controller.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Laravel's [date mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators), this handles the accessing and mutating dates going into and out of the database for you much like it does with `created_at` and the other default dates.

Basically, you need to add the `date` field to the `$dates` array on your model like so:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at', // Add if you're using timestamps on the model
        'updated_at', // Add if you're using timestamps on the model
        'deleted_at', // Add if you're using softDeletes on the model
        'date'
    ];
}
```

This way when the model is persisted to the database it's done so as a `DATETIME`, whereas when it is being read from the database into your model it will be a `Carbon` instance

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is already the case. I forgot to add it to my question i'll add it now.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your carbon function is ok. But why it does not work, don't understand. But I have solution using PHP date function.

```
public function setDateAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['date'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($value));
}
```